# Is Ice cream sandwich more aggressively closing apps in background?

Tags: android, memory, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I have been receiving reports from customers in the field that my app is closing (not force-closing, just closing) when put into the background for a period of time (10-15 minutes). This did not used to be the case. It is as if Android is being more aggressive about reducing the number of simultaneously running applications and thereby reducing the overall memory pressure on the device.

While this is a good thing overall, I am getting complaints and customers believe that my app is malfunctioning because this did not used to be standard behavior.

Can anyone confirm if yes, ICS is in fact more aggressively closing apps, and if so, if there are any new and recommended steps to reduce the likelihood that my app will be closed, other than the always true and always glib "use less memory"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It highly depends on the device. On a device like the Nexus S with "only" 384 MB of RAM available to apps, windows and apps are killed more aggressively indeed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's in the background for 10-15 minutes, why is it important for it to remain running? You can always handle saving the state of the activity in `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`, and simply restore state the next time the user opens the activity (in `onResume()`). If it's a long-running background process, you should probably run that in a service.

Comment: I think the main issue is that we have a startup sequence that connects to a service, downloads data and draws it. Before, only onPause was called, so it was super-fast to restore. Now, we have to go through the startup sequence again. We could do a bunch of eng work to serialize out our state and restore it quickly....it would be easier if the OS could freeze the state + page it out vs totally destroy it. Given these changes, what is the optimal design pattern now for apps like ours?

Comment: Just as an idea, possibly cache a local copy of the last downloaded data, and restore from that, while spawning a thread to download the more recent data in the background. That way, the user at least sees some accurate data right away, even if it isn't the most up-to-date.

Comment: Not to mention, this behavior affects apps you have no control over - very few apps I have seen take the trouble to completely restore their state after a restart.  (Having to keep logging back in to a web page or online banking just because I switched to another app for a minute is a big pain.)